# Вынесение за пределы цикла

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
function new_select(id, obj) {
 array_s = obj;
 array_int = document.getElementById(id);
 for(i = 1; i <= array_s.length; i++) {
  var array_value = array_s[i][1];
  var array_text = array_s[i][0];
 }
 array_int.innerHTML += '<b>'+array_title+'</b>'+array_value+' '+array_text;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы код:

```
array_int.innerHTML += '<b>'+array_title+'</b>'+array_value+' '+array_text;
```

работал **за пределами цикла**. Как сделать?

Comment: А сейчас не работает? И зачем надо снаружи?

Comment: объявите переменные за пределами цикла

Comment: @Spectre, asd = array_value; объявляю за пределами цикла, далее alert(sd) и не срабатывает.

Comment: Ну за пределами цикла будут доступны последние значения  array_s. Если asd не доступен, то может и значения нет? Проверьте array_s.

Comment: @forum3, в цикле оно успешно работает, а вот за циклом - нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

немного уличной магии

```
function new_select(id, obj) {
 array_s = obj;
var array_value ='';
var array_text ='';
 array_int = document.getElementById(id);
 for(i = 1; i <= array_s.length; i++) {
  array_value += array_s[i][1];
  array_text += array_s[i][0];
 }
 array_int.innerHTML += '<b>'+array_title+'</b>'+array_value+' '+array_text;
}
```